# Custom UITableViewCell sometimes not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am facing a weird problem. I want to display a custom cell without highlighting it. My `UITableViewCell` in my table has 5 elements in it like UILabel, UIImage etc. The problem is when I tap on the cell sometimes alertview is not displayed. This is the code in my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:LocalizedString(@"Please input") delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
            return;
```

I was doing a wide research about it. Firsly, I changed:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone
```

to

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor myCellColor];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
```

Since I don't want highlighting, I set the highlight color of the cell to the cell background color but the problem with that, it is highlighting the separator as well. So when I tap the color of seperator changes and it looks not nice.

I was wondering how to solve this issue without highligthing the custom cell.

Edit note:

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is always called but the AlertView is not always displayed.

Doesn't matter simple UIAlertController or UIAlertView. Both are sometimes not displayed.

Comment: try to show `UIAlertView` in main thread , and you should stop using it , it is deprecated

Comment: How do you detect a touch on your cell? Using the tableView delegate or something else?

Comment: I use default tableView delegate and use didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Does your alertview code always get called and just sometimes it's not shown? You can use NSLog to test this if necessary.

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath is always called but the alertview is not displayed sometimes. Actually I put the alertview just to show you, instead AlertView, my main code is not sometimes working. But same for alertview as well that its not always displayed.

Comment: post your `tableView` `delegate` method so can rectify ..

Comment: need more code, and did you try with `nslog(@"select")`, in `didselectrowatindexpath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you covered you entire cell with some UI components so you cant really touch the cell to execute `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method see example image below.

The entire green portion of `cell` and is `uibutton` light blue:

[image]

So this wont detect your touch everytime over cell and execute `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method properly ..

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I have many components in the cell. Imagine instagram or facebook timeline cells. Like that. But I dont get why it sometimes not responding and sometimes it does for the point i touch.

Comment: yes may be it is your problem, you can do this by adding a button and action method over cell i can post the example code of it if you really need ..

Comment: You mean a button over all components and a transparent one?

Comment: its upto you what you need to do by adding adding button instead  `didSelect` method which is not calling everytime ..

Comment: @gbesler have you tried to add transparent button over the cell ? still id display some time ?

Comment: @vaibhav solved the issue with the transparent button. many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your delegate method. Autocomplete can sometimes be funny and insert didDeselectRowAtIndexPath instead of didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Its didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I double checked.

Comment: I would recommend you use UIAlertController instead. UIAlertView is deprecated. Anyway... did you implement - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex in your view controller?

Comment: It is not about UIAlertView it is just to show you. My main code is also not working.

Comment: @gbesler please post your entire main code including alertview in didSelectRowAtIndexPath so we can help.

Comment: Doesnt matter what the code is there. Even I put there a simple UIAlertController or UIAlertView code it is not always displayed.